# Application insights clarification and what is my app service doing?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

When I look at request tracing in azure application insights I sometimes see this thing:
[image]

This question holds 2 parts:
Is it correct that the app service icon part is the outgoing dependency and the app service plan icon is the actual execution of "my" code in the app?

The second part: if that is true; why does it sometimes look like it does on the right side of the image (with a much large dependency duration then actual execution, 1.7 mins to 309 ms).
I have checked my performance and diagnostics and the cpu is not

Answer (score 0):

Application insights clarification and what is my app service doing?

I understand that the dependencies time also tracked in the Request calls as per this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-diagnostics#details-of-the-selected-telemetry) of Azure Monitor Transaction diagnostics telemetry details.

[image]

Above image taken from the same reference. it is showing the levels of tracking such as: Request > Dependency > Exception - Here, every level is a component.

Some are expandible components, and some are non-collapsible components.

> This question holds 2 parts: Is it correct that the app service icon part is the outgoing dependency and the app service plan icon is the actual execution of “my” code in the app?

In your case, App Service is the main component and App Service Plan is the expandible component which is a part of App Service Request and consists of exceptions and external dependencies.

> The second part: if that is true; why does it sometimes look like it does on the right side of the image (with a much large dependency duration then actual execution, 1.7 mins to 309 ms).

I believe the sum of the execution of dependency components duration and exception duration is the main component execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So can you confirm that "my" code is executed under the app service plan component? 

Then what is the major delay (of a minute or so) before the execution starts? 
Is there something underlying in azure that is struggling to keep up?